# Can't shell jhbuild on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9)

Tags: shell, terminal, gtk, osx-mavericks, jhbuild

I'm trying to install GTK+ on my Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9) laptop. I'm following the instructions at https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show//Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building?action=show&redirect=GTK%252B%252FOSX%252FBuilding#Procedure . I've managed to install jhbuild. However, when I try doing the command "~/.local/bin/jhbuild shell" (without quotes) in Terminal, I get the following error messages:

```
  File "/Users/mansnilsson/Source/jhbuild/jhbuild/config.py", line 247, in load
    execfile(filename, config)
  File "/Users/mansnilsson/.jhbuildrc", line 555, in <module>
    execfile(_userrc)
  File "/Users/mansnilsson/.jhbuildrc-custom", line 113, in <module>
    setup_sdk(target=_target, sdk_version="native", architectures=[_default_arch])
  File "/Users/mansnilsson/.jhbuildrc", line 295, in setup_sdk
    module_extra_env["pkg-config"] = {'CFLAGS': os.environ['CFLAGS'] + ' --std=gcc89'}
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'CFLAGS'
jhbuild: could not load config file
```

I've been intensely Googling for a solution to this problem. One user suggested that I have to edit the .jhbuildrc-custom file, comment out all ifs and elifs for the _target variable's value, and just set the value to "10.7" myself, but that didn't help. Why am I unable to run the command?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in the current gtk-osx version.

Comment: Current being from where? Specific repo? Which version? Can you provide more info?

Comment: JHbuild will always download the newest modulesets when you install it as in the instructions. You really don't need to know anything else, just run it.